# Word that describes either a team or a single player

Tags: single-word-requests, sports

What is a good word for describing an entity (usually in a sports event) that can consist of one or more players?

The idea is to give a name to a class (in code) for such a group (or player) within a game.

Comment: An option is to go with _team_, and allow teams to have one player. Not a language-based approach, but software-design-wise, this has many advantages. You need no distinction between singles and doubles games in sports like tennis, you can assign teams to your competition planning before the players are known, and you don't need different logic for sports with competing teams or sports with competing individuals.

Comment: One number-neutral term you might use is _participant_, which may refer to an individual entered in a competition or to team so entered. Another option is _competitor_, although it isn't as unweighted a descriptive term as _participant_.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In some contexts it doesn't sound as natural as *team*, but **side** fits.

> In this game there are three sides.

Or

> Each side has one or two players.

Or

> Each side tries to keep the other sides from collecting the erychronolite before the magnum-sploty awakes.

But as oerkelens says, if you're naming a class in code, I should think *team* would be better, since it's not as ambiguous a word as *side*.

Answer (score 1):

*Opponent*.

The [American Heritage Dictionary](https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=opponent) says

> 1. One that opposes another or others, as in a battle, contest, or debate: a political opponent.

Comment: It's not necessarily the opponent. It could be the "home" team/player as well.

Comment: They are *all* opponents :-)

Comment: @and256 - All for one and one for all! ...and every man for himself..! :-)

Answer (score 1):

> **SQUAD** *noun* [plural *noun*: **squads**]:
>   a small group of people having a particular task.
>   "an assassination *squad*"
>
> **synonyms**: team, crew, gang, band, cell, body, mob, outfit, force 
>   "an assassination *squad*"
>
> •a small number of soldiers assembled for drill or assigned to some special task, especially an infantry unit forming part of a platoon.
>
> **synonyms**: detachment, detail, unit, platoon, battery, troop, patrol, *squadron*, cadre, commando, tiger team "an elite reconnaissance *squad*"
>
> •***a group of sports players or competitors*** from which a team is chosen.
>   "eleven first-string players on the Nebraska *squad*"
>
> [**GOOGLE**](https://www.google.com/search?sourceid=navclient&aq=&oq=squad+defi&ie=UTF-8&rlz=1T4VRHB_enUS620US620&q=squad+definition&gs_l=hp..0.0l3j0i22i30l2.0.0.0.22277...........0._6ogLgh6oyo&gws_rd=ssl)

Comment: A one-man squad sounds just as bad to me as a one-man team, and for sports events, *team* is a much better word in general than *squad*.

Comment: +1 @Peter Shor - how generous of you to share your perspicacity with me. You should post your "team" suggestion. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Could Challenger work? I could see that as a single player, but also a team, although the definition doesn't completely fit.

Answer (score 0):

Although an [entry](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/entry) (or [entrant](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/entrant)) might usually imply a single [contestant](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/contestant), in at least one sport (that of kings) it can mean [more than one](http://www1.drf.com/help/help_glossary.html#E) (6th one down under the Es).